# ¿Cómo puedo usar un select2 cargado por YiiBooster con cache y actualizar su valor?

Tags: select2, yii, yiibooster, cache

Tengo un problema que se me presenta con yiibooster y un `<select>` con mucha información generada con select2 de Yiibooster.

El problema es que deseo cargar una lista de ciudades con un límite de aproximadamente 1500 registros, todos agrupados por departamento.  Para esto hice este código en mi modelo:

```
public function getCiudades() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->order = "ID asc";
    $ciudades = Ciudad::model()->cache(86500)->findAll($criteria);
    return CHtml::listData($ciudades, "ID", "Nombre",  'departamento.Nombre');
}
```

Aquí el sistema carga la información que necesito y todo funciona muy bien, y esta información se traduce del modelo a la vista en un `select2` generado desde *YiiBooster* así:

```
echo $form->select2Group($model, 'Ciudad', array(
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'asDropDownList' => true,
                        "data" => $model->getCiudades(),
                        'options' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione o busque la ciudad',
                            'width' => '100%'
                        )
                    )
                ));
```

Esto funciona bien, el problema es que el render tarda demasiado. Para corregir este problema, usé el cache de archivos de *yii* y coloqué el fragmento de código que genera esta lista así:

```
if ($this->beginCache("contacto.ciudades", array("duration" => 86400))) {
    echo $form->select2Group($model, 'Ciudad', array(
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'asDropDownList' => true,
                        "data" => $model->getCiudades(),
                        'options' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione o busque la ciudad',
                            'width' => '100%'
                        )
                    )
                ));
   $this->endCache();
}
```

Desde luego el sistema carga muy rápido, pero ahora tengo un problema al cargar de nuevo la lista con un valor ya guardado, como el cache es estático, el valor del registro no se cambia dinámicamente y vuelve a mostrar el último valor guardado la última vez que el cache se generó.

Tampoco puedo colocar un valor menor al tiempo del cache porque necesito reutilizar esa lista en varias partes.

¿Hay alguna forma de colocar este cache a los elementos `<option>` y `<optgroup>` de la lista?

Comment: Holas te cuento que cuando son demasiados datos para mostrar es mejor usar un plugin como Typeahead.js para poder realizar este tipo de listados, typeahead es un autocompletador, tu le agregas un array de datos y cuando tu empezas a escribir en el textinput el plugin te va mostrando sugerencias de los datos del array que tu agregaste. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, intente usar typeahead antes pero hay un problema de los usuarios que escriben lo que quieran, una forma efectiva de controlar la informacion que se necesita es usando un select, el problema de este es que en muchos datos la busqueda es engorrosa, por eso opte por select2

Comment: Si ese es justamente el problema con el typehead pero solo necesitas validar en tu modelo el dato enviado con una validacion personalizada, haciendo la consulta de la existencia del dato ingresado, si es un dato erroneo devuelves el error correspondiente puedes usar el form con ajax o sin ajax para realizar esto. Saludos

Comment: Hola, creo que encontre la solucion y tiene que ver con un problema de yii y el manejo de los objetos en grandes volumenes de datos, yii es muy lento al analizar toda esta informacion y al parecer el tema va en como le paso la informacion mas resumida a yii, voy a terminar la solucion y explico bien detallado lo que hice

Comment: Has considerado usar la opción de carga de datos con Ajax de select2?

Comment: Por supuesto, pero mi problema ya no tiene que ver con el componente, he logrado acelerar por mucho la velocidad de carga cambiando las busquedas de usar modelos a realizar busquedas mas concretas usando CDBCommand

Comment: @JorgeRicardoSanchezCocunubo Amigo, si lo has resuelto, por favor responde esta pregunta (en la caja grande de abajo) para apoyo a la comunidad :D . ¡Buen día!.

Answer (score 2):

Ya tiempo que hice esta pregunta, luego de haber hecho un análisis de mi código me di cuenta que el problema no lo tenia el *Select2*, mi problema de base era la información que traía para llenar este *Select*, es decir.

Para la carga del *Select* tenía que ir a la tabla `Ciudades`, con un valor de aproximadamente 1500 registros, todos los cargaba desde el modelo base `Ciudad`, el cual traía absolutamente toda la información del modelo, esto precisamente es lo que hace lenta la carga, porque mientras llena toda la información se toma un tiempo muy largo.

Investigando un poco busqué una solución basada en *SQL* directo que no dependiera del modelo (no tanto), entonces encontré una sentencia que puedo aplicar directamente en *SQL* usando el modelo base con `CreateCommand` así:

```
$elementos = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
            ->select('e.ID as ID, e.Nombre as Nombre, e.Categoria as Categoria')
            ->from('Elemento e')
            ->where("e.Clasificacion='Elemento' and e.Servicio=1 and e.Estado=1")
            ->queryAll();
    return CHtml::listData($elementos, "ID", "Nombre", 'Categoria');
```

Fuera del código que imparte el *Select*, lo importante aquí es esta linea: **-setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)**, esta línea convertirá tu *select* a *objeto*, de esta forma lo puedes usar directo con el `CHtml::listData` sin tener que convertir información.

Espero que esta respuesta les ayude a solucionar sus problemas con *Select2* y *YII*.